# Permalinks for parent/child pages and custom post types

Tags: permalinks

I have this custom structure set for my permalinks: /archive/%postname%

With this, my URLs show as example.com/parent/child, which is the desired behavior.  However, I'm adding a custom post type and this permalink structure is causing undesired URLs for the CPT.  I want the permalink to be example.com/news/headline, but I'm getting example.com/archive/news/headline.

Here's my CPT:

```
 register_post_type('news', array(
  ...
  'public'   => true,
  'rewrite'  => array('slug' => 'news'),
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'page-attributes', 'editor', 'custom-fields')
));
```

Is there a better permalink structure I could use to achieve the URLs I require?  Or is there something missing/wrong in my CPT that would fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the `with_front` on `rewrite` while `register_post_type`.

In your case:

```
register_post_type('news', array(
  ...
  'public'   => true,
  'rewrite'  => array('slug' => 'news', 'with_front'=> false),
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'page-attributes', 'editor', 'custom-fields')
));
```

Comment: This is what worked for me.  At first my CPT pages were showing 404 after adding "with_front => false", I then disabled & reenabled all plugins and it started working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the "Post name" permalink structure, which is the same as `/%postname%/`. Pages will use the `/parent/child/` structure, and your CPT - as-is - will use `/news/%postname%/`.

Comment: I get a 404 error for all child pages when trying to use "Post name" permalink structure.